# Why are single-purpose accounts not eligible for removal?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, accounts

Yesterday, I saw this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321976/degrading-from-itext-5-4-2-to-4-2-0

[image]
This question has only been viewed 24 times and it received 6 down-votes. In other words: 25% of the people who saw this question, downvoted it.

The original question was in broken English, so I edited it, changing words like "degrating" into "degrading". Then I looked at the profile of the person who posted the question, [yogesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4528625/yogesh). I noticed that this account was created moments before the question was asked.

My guess is that this account was created for the single purpose of asking an question of which the person who posted it knew that the question would receive many down-votes. It wouldn't surprise me if [yogesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4528625/yogesh) had another account on StackOverflow and that he or she didn't want to compromise that account by posting an inappropriate question.

So I flagged the question, but my flag was declined:
[image]

In answer to the question *Why should we remove a new account?* my answer would be: *Because there's a 99% chance that this is a bogus account.*

But why not start with removing the question? I wanted to flag it as "poor quality" but for some reason I couldn't pick that option. The question is, in any case, off topic: it is about a problem that can not be produced with a recent version of the tool that is used. The problem of the OP is caused by his or her desire to replace a recent version of the tool with a version that dates from 2009. The functionality he or she needs in the 2009 version was added much more recently.

Once the question is removed, it wouldn't surprise me if we wouldn't get another question from the person who created this account. I'm pretty sure he or she has another StackOverflow account (but that is something probably only a moderator can tell).

What happens with such accounts? Are they kept to keep the statistics up (we have X accounts, that is Y more than last month)? Or are inactive accounts cleaned up on a regular basis to keep the statistics clean?

Comment: FWIW [Very Low Quality flags are not available for questions under close and triage review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/152859)

Comment: Do you have proof? How do you know, for certain, that this is such an account? You are making assumptions that you can't back up. Hence - the flag was declined and rightfully so.

Comment: Thanks about the answer about the Very Low Quality flags. That's clear. As for the question *Do you have proof?* Obviously not, because I don't have access to IP addresses. A moderator might have, hence my question: is there a way to find proof that confirms or contradicts my suspicion?

Comment: I think its a bit presumptuous to assume that an account is bogus simply because it was created shortly before asking the question... My understanding is that one should always focus on the quality of the question when voting/flagging and not the person.

Comment: All in all I don't see any account problems here. If the question is a problem, address it. But a single-shot account (if that is the case) isn't really an issue. Having multiple accounts is not outlawed. And accounts are only ever deleted upon request or if from known spammers or those under the age of 13.

Comment: Is it also presumptuous to assume that somebody just downvoted two of my questions because I posted this question here? No reason was given why those two questions were downvoted. I don't really care about losing 4 reputation points. I have answered more than a thousand questions and only asked four, the downvotes on questions can be neglected when compared to the upvotes on my answer, but still: downvoting questions without explaining why is somewhat cowardous.

Comment: Would have been better if you flagged other and presented your suspicions, rather than your conclusion.  Also, see the "meta effect".

Comment: Just because you use SO to support users of your software doesn't mean that SO should remove questions about it that you dislike. There's no issue with asking questions about "legacy" software on SO, they are just as valid as other questions... this particular one was indeed a crap question, but it seems like what you're really upset about is that someone is trying to use an old version of iText, rather than real concern about someone having a "single-purpose" account.

Comment: @eddie_cat I am always very clear towards people who deliberately choose to use an obsolete, unsupported, unofficial version of iText. There are many questions from people like that, but I only ask SO to remove a question if it's really bad (even you agree that it was indeed a crap question). So far, I have answered 1117 questions on SO and if I query [how Unsung I am](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i), I see 641 accepted answers and only 27% that remain "unscored". Doesn't that give me some credibility? ;-)

Comment: You don't need to ask moderators/flag to remove that sort of question.  Downvote, vote to close, and don't answer (and don't edit, either!).  Automatic deletion will clean it up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I declined that flag, for the reasons I provided. I'm not going to delete an account of a user just because they asked a single bad question.

All users here have to start somewhere. Most start by asking questions. There are tens of thousands of users who started by asking a single question, including many of the people who will read this.

If you have evidence that a new account is being used to circumvent a suspension or question ban (asking duplicated questions of another user, odd interactions between two accounts, clear vote fraud, trolling, etc.), you can present that in a flag and we might act on that. Asking us to delete an account without any evidence being presented is almost always going to lead to us declining that flag.

For the record, I did look around that account to see if there was anything odd about it, mainly because I was confused about your flag, but found no evidence that this was anything other than a new user.

There's another factor here that made me uncomfortable with your request, and that's your first comment on the question:

> The cost of a license will be lower than the effort you'll spend trying to get that work. Please tell us what company you are working for and we'll explain how it works. If you're a startup, you may even get "one year free capacity rental." Do the right thing. Support open source project. Don't abuse them! Read the final answer in my book The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow and you'll understand.

Given that you appear to work for a company that sells licenses to this software, this leaves a bad taste in my mouth. It comes across as you wanting to delete an account asking about how to use an earlier version of the library that your commercial licenses aren't needed for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can remove that comment if you want to. I am indeed the original developer of iText. I am very passionate about what I do and I can be grumpy when I see that somebody would prefer to downgrade to a version dating five years back only because of the fact that the current open source version expects users to publish their code under the same license. The license was changed from the MPL/LGPL to the AGPL because *Givers need to set limits because takers rarely do.* People can still use iText for free if they publish their own source code for free too.